# Checking Nesting of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

There can two sets of objects

First can be a straight forward where is no children

```
const noChildObj = [{
    "id": 1,
    "label": ["Description"],
    "lines": 1,
    "type": "string",
    "precision": 2,
    "width": 167.8
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "label": ["Information", "Ratio"],
    "lines": 2,
    "type": "number",
    "precision": 2,
    "width": 167.8
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "label": ["Tracking", "Error"],
    "lines": 2,
    "type": "number",
    "precision": 2,
    "width": 167.8
}]
```

So,in this case, there is no child , so property 'width' is at the topmost layer.
Second is  where nesting of objects occur

So each  object in the array will have a child object

```
[{
    "id": "257",
    "label": [""],
    "lines": 1,
    "children": [{
        "id": "Description",
        "label": ["Dates"],
        "lines": 1,
        "type": "date",
        "precision": null,
        "width": 839
    }]
}, {
    "id": "258",
    "label": ["Cumulative Return"],
    "lines": 1,
    "children": [{
        "id": 12,
        "label": ["Russell 1000 Value - Price Return"],
        "lines": 1,
        "type": "number",
        "precision": 2,
        "width": 839
    }]
}]
```

Here each object has a child object where the property width exists

This nesting is not limited to just 1 level
It can go upto 4 levels

So my use case requires if the innermost child has width undefined or not

I do realise that through recursion , we can traverse and find out..
But is there any function which can do it in less lines of code..may be in lodash

Please help

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: It's unclear what you're looking for.  Is it a function accepting a "children"-based tree and returning a boolean which is true if and only if `width` appears on the leaf nodes?  Do you want to add the widths (recursively) of all the child nodes?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Know only how to do with recursion:

```js
const objArray = [{
    "id": 1,
    "label": ["Description"],
    "lines": 1,
    "type": "string",
    "precision": 2,
    "width": 167.8
}, {
    "id": "257",
    "label": [""],
    "lines": 1,
    "children": [{
        "id": "Description",
        "label": ["Dates"],
        "lines": 1,
        "type": "date",
        "precision": null,
        "width": 839
    }]
}]

const getWidthDeep = (el) => el.children && el.children[0]
  ? getWidthDeep(el.children[0])
  : el.width

const result = objArray.map(getWidthDeep)
console.log(result)
```